# No SDK Found a specified Location Xamarin

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, xamarin

i have looked for a long time now, trying a lot of different solutions but to no success.

So if I try and run the Android sdk, Java SKD and Android NDK is specified but not Android SKD ad if I brows to the Folder, It dosent Accept it My SKD location is in here : C:\Users\Jody(Work)\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

And here is an image of Whats in the Folder : [image]

Zoomed Image : [image]

Please help as I need to get xamarin running for work.

Thanks In advance

Comment: I suspect it doesn't like the "(Work)" in the path - I think it's particular about the use of special characters

Comment: Really, so I should change my PC Name ?

Comment: Also how do I change this folders Name ?

Comment: Thanks man, this worked, I had to Format my system and when I renamed the Main user file, to a simple one, No special chariters, Then Xamarin installed Just fine hay :)